# Visual Studio Code - Redshift Driver

Tags: visual-studio-code, amazon-redshift, driver, sqltools

[image]

My driver on Visual Studio Code don't working. My problem is SQLTOOLS - I deleted this extension and downloaded it again but my problem didn't get fixed.

I don't understand, and I try another driver but it's the same problem.

Comment: The message says is it trying to connect to `127.0.0.1`, which is your 'localhost' (your own computer). It should be trying to connect to the Redshift cluster's URL, not your own computer.